# Ring-Homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Then the problem is to show that there is a ring-homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ if and only if $n$ is odd.

My effort : let $\phi$ be such a ring homomorphism (apart from the zero-map). then if $\phi(1)\ =\ a$ and $1.1\ =\ 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ so in $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ we must have $a^{2}\ =\ a$. Moreover $\phi(1+1)\ =\ \phi(0)\ =\ 2a$ and so $|2a|$ must divide $2n$. But I can't deduce anything from these.

Thanks

Comment: when will $\mathbb{Z}_n$ have idempotent elements ?

Comment: You made an error in your argument: you meant $2n$ must divide $2a$.

Comment: @Hurkyl :- i am saying that order of $2a$ must divide $2n$

Comment: I would suggest you to at least see you can not have a non zero ring homomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $\phi : \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4$

you should be able to see that $\phi(\bar{0})=\bar{0}$ i.e., $\phi(2.\bar{1})=\bar{0}$ i.e., $2.\phi(\bar{1})=\bar{0}$

Now only possibility for $\phi(\bar{1})$ excluding $\bar{0}$ is $\phi(\bar{1})=\bar{2}$.

But then, your map should preserve multiplication property also...

I mean you should have $\phi(\bar{1})=\phi(\bar{1}.\bar{1})=\phi(\bar{1}).\phi(\bar{1})=\bar{2}.\bar{2}=\bar{0}$

so the only possibility which we have got is not even well defined as $\phi(\bar{1})$ is taking two distinct values.

More generally $\bar{1}$ should be send to $\bar{n}$ and in that case, for similar reasn as above,

$\phi(\bar{1})=\phi(\bar{1}.\bar{1})=\phi(\bar{1}).\phi(\bar{1})=\bar{n}.\bar{n}=\bar{n}^2$

the worst case we should not have is $n^2$ being divided by $2n$

i.e., $n$ being divided by $2$.. which means $n$ has to be odd....

I hope you can do the other way....

Comment: @Koushik :- thanks :)...i saw by seeing the cases uptil $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ but slipped that observation of sending $1$ to $n$...

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is even then 
$$n^2=2^2(n/2)^2=4(n/2)(n/2)=(2n)(n/2)=0$$

but in that case, $n^2=n$ so $n$ is not even (that is, $n$ is odd.)